# Site does not exist, a2ensite (AWS)

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, vim

I am following this guide http://www.mornin.org/blog/scalable-wordpress-amazon-web-services/

When I do this part of the guide, sudo a2ensite newsite.com

I get site newsite.com does not exist, can someone perhaps point me towards what I may have missed?

Thanks